# Spark read CSV with carriage return followed by new line in text field

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, newline

I am trying to read a csv on Spark using Scala.

One of the text fields *can* contain carriage returns (\c), followed by new line feeds (\n).
The end of a proper row is also marked in the same way, carriage return followed by line feed. You can already picture what happens when the aforementioned text field contains them as well. This occurs once in a while, but when it does the reading function interprets them as the starting of a new row in the file and generates an annoying column shift plus some extra rows containing some portion of this text field.

I have read many threads with problems similar to mine. I tried most of the solutions but nothing works. At the moment I am using the following code to read the CSV, however it produces the annoying shift:

```
val df1 = (spark.read
.option("delimiter", "¦")
.option("header",true)
.option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1")
.option("header", "true")
.option("inferSchema", "true")
.csv(s3Location))
```

I need the encoding because if I read the file without it, the fields delimiter (which is `¦`) is not properly displayed. I tried `.option("multiline", "true")`, to escape the characters, but nothing works.

The only solution I managed to create is to drop those rows using `.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")`. However, it seems quite drastic since they could carry useful information.